# Paginate an AngularJS data table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have gathered some JSON (dummy) data in a users table.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module
app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = root + "/users"
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.users = data.data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
.search-box {
  margin: 5px;
}

.panel-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-container .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.table-container table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" data-ng-app="usersApp">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="usersCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group search-box">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search User" data-ng-model="search">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Full name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Suite</th>                 
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td><a href="mailto:{{user.email}}">{{user.email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.street}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.suite}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The table has only 10 rows but, in a real-world app, there is a lot more data to manage so it needs to be paginated. The above one could have 3 rows per page (except the 4th one, which should have one).

Question(s):

1. Does AngularJS have a built-in, easy way to paginate such a table?
2. If not, what are the best alternatives?

Comment: There are numerous angular table/grid modules available on web. Try them out and pick one with features you like

Comment: If you are writing the API where you will be getting the data from, I'd recommend doing the pagination on the server and just returning the records for the current page. You would just send a pagination object back and forth with the current page, number per page, total pages, etc. and use this for your pagination UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angularjs don't have built-in pagination feature. You have to use some third-party modules like [angular-ui-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-grid). OR you can try this `<https://codepen.io/khilnani/pen/qEWojX>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngInfiniteScroll** for pagination. https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/